# value is not stored automatically in the database after executing the script

Tags: php

This is the  php code to show fb style like / unlike which works fine after inserting values in the database manually..but i want my values to be inserted and stored in the database automatically after executing the script

```
include('db.php');
if($_REQUEST['postId'])
{
    $userip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

    mysql_query("update likes set likes=likes+1 where post_id= ".$_REQUEST['postId']);

    mysql_query("INSERT INTO ip (userip,post_id) VALUES('".$userip."','".$_REQUEST['postId']."')");

    $total_likes = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM facebook_collapsed_likes where post_id = ".$_REQUEST['postId']." ");
    $likes = mysql_fetch_array($total_likes);
    $likes = $likes['likes'];
}
echo $likes;
```

Comment: Your codes are [Sql Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerable.

Comment: Please be explicit with the error or problem you are having .... What values are not been inserted ???? What error are you having ???

Comment: www.mysite.com/filename.php?postId=my_post_id ...while running it on the address bar ...it works fine but i dont know why its not working on the click button i have provided in the page